# Is it possible to render 3D texture with depth buffer in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm trying to implement some program and using this classic code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
```

Bind depth buffer.

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width,
 height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,  GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);
```

Bind several **3D** textures:

```
glGenTextures(targets.size(), textures);
for (auto &target : targets) {
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, textures[ix]);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, depth, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
}
  glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + ix, textures[ix], 0);
  buffers[ix] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + ix;
  ++ix;
}
glDrawBuffers(targets.size(), buffers);
```

And it do not work, indicating `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS` error. I supposed, that, since my textures are layered, there could be a problem with not layered depth buffer. I have created it in the same way as I did it for 3D textures, so I removed depth buffer. This solved task, now my framebuffer is working, rendering completes and so on.

But what if I need to render each layer, having depth buffer attached? Is this functionality supported, are there some seldom api calls to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If one attached image is layered, then *all* attached images must be layered. So if you want to do layered rendering with a depth buffer, the depth image must *also* be layered.

So instead of using a renderbuffer, you should use a 2D array texture with a depth format.

Comment: I don't believe there are 3D textures with depth format. So it has to be a 2D array texture.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: There's no restriction on that in the OpenGL API.

Comment: A little too long to quote here in its entirety, but check the last paragraph on page 191 of the 4.5 spec, starting with "Textures with a base internal format of DEPTH_COMPONENT, ...".

Comment: @RetoKoradi: It's page 193 of 4.5. At least, in the most recent version of the spec.

Comment: Could you provide small example how to initialize such a buffer(or put here some url with explanation). I expected something, that makes possible to render 3d texture with use of depth buffer, but at the same time, I don't need depth texture itself, so I'll discard it after rendering.

Comment: @VasiliyStavenko: If you can create a 3D texture, you can create a 2D array texture too. The overall idea (and even the function you use) is no different.