# Is it possible to create a cubemap renderbuffer?

Tags: opengl

I have a FBO whose color attachment is a cubemap texture - this is needed because I need to render my scene to a cubemap.

However, I also need a depth attachment to render it properly. I wanted to use a renderbuffer instead of a texture since I will not be sampling it directly.

Is it possible to create a "cubemap" renderbuffer or I really need to create another texture? Using a normal renderbuffer doesn't work, since the framebuffer fails to be created with `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS` error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180558/is-it-possible-to-render-3d-texture-with-depth-buffer-in-opengl

Comment: @tuket That asker wants a 3D texture, but this asker wants a cubemap - they are different. I'll edit the title.

Comment: Don't you have to render a cubemap by rendering each face separately? Then couldn't you just use a normal depth buffer and clear it in between faces?

Comment: (actually, the answer to the question tuket linked says that won't work, because they must all be layered)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missread. Well, I think you cannot draw to a cubemap directly. What works for sure is to do 6 draw passes one for each face of the cube. You can specify which face you want to draw to with `glFramebufferTexture2D` and passing each of the enums starting from `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X` https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glFramebufferTexture

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have a look at [Point Light Shadows](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Point-Shadows)

Comment: @Syncit Thanks for the link! I didn't know that was possible. I think that will be very useful to the OP as well.

Comment: @Syncit Note that in this tutorial he is attaching a cubemap texture to the depth attachment and explicitly disabling the color attachment. In my case, I am attaching a cubemap texture to the color attachment and I want to use a renderbuffer for the depth attachment. They are different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, but it still didn't solve my question :( For now, I am assuming it is not possible and using a cubemap texture for the depth attachment as well... (not sure why the question was closed)